# Laravel MySQL Comprobar si existe un registro

Tags: mysql, laravel

alguien podria ayudarme a corregir mi código de laravel para que antes de insertar un nuevo registro, comprobar si existe ese registro? (para evitar duplicados) es decir, si existe un registro igual al que se va a insertar no permitir el registro , si no permitir que se inserte.

Cabe mencionar que lo que quiero validar es una columna foranea y llega como valor en un select de formulurio. Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
    $ciclo=$request->idCiclo; //Guardo el valor que recibo del formulario

    $existencia = DB::table('planespago')   //realizo la sentencia para saber si existe
    ->select('idCiclo')
    ->where('idCiclo', '=', $ciclo);

   if ($existencia = $ciclo) {   //aqui valido si son iguales en el campo de la db y 
                                  lo que llego del formulario
       return json_encode('no puedes registrar otro');

    }else{

      return  json_encode('creado');

    }
```

Pero no me hace bien la validación y pasa direcctamente que es verdad aunque yo elija un valor que no existe

Comment: y no tienes creado el modelo de esa tabla?

Answer (score 3):

Posiblemente se deba a errores de tipografía.

Primero en tu consulta te falta usar el método `get` para traer los datos

```
$existencia = DB::table('planespago')
    ->select('idCiclo')
    ->where('idCiclo', '=', $ciclo)
    ->get();
```

Y en tu validación estás usando solo un `=`para hacer tu condición, cuando deberías usar `==`

```
if ($existencia == $ciclo)
```

Si no se debe a eso, es posible que en tu condicional estés comparando mal las variables y debas cambiar a esto:

```
if ($existencia->idCiclo == $ciclo)
```

La otra vía de solución es cambiar la condición a:

```
if(count($existencia) >= 1)
```

Comment: tienes razón me olvide del ->get(). la validación no funciono ni uno ni el otro probe esto if (count($existencia)>=1) y si lo realiza

Comment: Ok, bueno editaré la respuesta para que incluya la opcion que dijiste que solucionó tu pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Es mas simple que eso, tenemos un helper que nos devuelve un booleano

```
DB::table('planespago')->where('idCiclo', $idCiclo)->exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

Guardas el valor que trae $request en la posición "idCiclo" , perfecto ten presente que esto es un INT por consiguiente debes compararlo con un dato que sea de un tipo similar.

```
$ciclo=$request->idCiclo;
```

Resumimos un poco esta linea de codigo realizando la consulta directamente al modelo (con el metodo find() no hace falta decirle get() ), ten presente que aquí se retorna un OBJETO de la clase PlanesPago.

```
$existencia = PlanesPago::find($ciclo);
```

Aquí es donde tienes el error , estas comparando una variable de tipo INT con una variable de tipo PlanesPago

```
if ($existencia = $ciclo)
```

La manera correcta seria

```
if($exitencia->idCiclo == $ciclo)
```

Incluso diría que puedes implementar el operador "===" ya que son del mismo tipo.

Espero esto sea de ayuda.